# Swift - Where does the point comes from?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having hard time understanding the simple function below. Where does the mysterious 'point' comes from ?

```
typealias Position = CGPoint
typealias Distance = CGFloat
typealias Region = Position -> Bool


func circle(radius: Distance) -> Region {
    return { point in
        sqrt(point.x * point.x + point.y * point.y) <= radius
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `circle` function returns a closure having this declaration:

```
(Position) -> Bool
```

`point` is the name of the parameter passed to the closure, of `Position` type - maybe rewriting the function as follows it's more clear:

```
func circle(radius: Distance) -> Region {
    let closure: Region = { (point: Position) -> Bool in
        return sqrt(point.x * point.x + point.y * point.y) <= radius
    }

    return closure
}
```

You can assign the return value of the `circle` function to a variable:

```
let closure = circle(1.0)
```

and then invoke it:

```
let p = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
closure(p)
```

The `p` parameter is what is called (and referenced as) `point` in the closure declaration

Answer (score 1):

The `point` refers to the argument of the closure you defined after the `return` statement. See more information here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

Your closure

```
{ point in
    sqrt(point.x * point.x + point.y * point.y) <= radius
}
```

Is understood from context to be

```
{ (point:Position) -> Bool in
    sqrt(point.x * point.x + point.y * point.y) <= radius
}
```

Which is equivalent to the function delaration

```
func anonymous(point:Position) -> Bool {
    return sqrt(point.x * point.x + point.y * point.y) <= radius
}
```

I have used the symbol anonymous here since a function must have a name, but that's just so the code is legal - it doesn't really have a name.